# C++ conversion from char* to byte array

Tags: c++, char, arrays

I would appreciate if someone could give me an example of how to convert char *variable to byte array and vice-versa in C++.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to convert a pointer into a byte array? And: C or C++? Please decide.

Comment: a const char* allready points to a byte array...

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: My "*No.*" was referring to your initial (1st?) version of your comment, stating a `char*` would be a "byte-array.", which definitly is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

If `std::vector<char>` is what you're after, then it's simply:

```
std::vector<char> byteArry(charPtr, charPtr + sizeOfCharPtr);
```

and the other way:

```
const char* charPtr = byteArry.data();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried anything you self, maybe google?

Anyways a char *variable is a char pointer, so you will need to know the size of the data and create a byte array in the same size.

After that you can do a [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)